# What is an elegant way to break out of a visit statement in Rascal MPL?

Tags: break, rascal

I'm using `visit` in rascal to iterate through a string. I would like to break out once I match a specific case. In other words, I would like to achieve this exact behavior:

```
str toVisit = "abcdefgh";

while(true) {
    visit(toVisit) {
        case /^bc/: println("before");
        case /^de/: break;
        case /^fg/: println("after");
    }

    break;
}
```

but without the while loop. There is no mention of this in [the manual page of visit](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Rascal/Expressions/Visit/). Hence my question: is there an elegant way to break out of a visit statement in Rascal MPL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`visit` is general better at recursive traversals then iterating, but `return` is the typical way people do break out of visits:

```
void myFunction() {
    visit (toVisit) {
        case /^bc/: println("before");
        case /^de/: return;
        case /^fg/: println("after");
    }
}
```

So that favors smaller functions :-)

Otherwise, regular expressions themselves have excellent backtracking behavior for searching linear patterns like that:

```
for (/<before:.*>bc<middle:.*>de<after:.*>fg/ := "abcdefgh") {
   println("match! <before> <middle> <after>");
   // fail brings you to the next match (also for visit, if, etc)
   fail;
   // break jumps out of the loop
   break;
   // continue brings you to the next match as well
   continue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So I take from this: as visit does recursive / iterative traversals, there is no way to directly break out of the thing unless a construct (function, loop etc.) is wrapped around it.

Comment: right. we have not added semantics for break and continue to visit. Although if you suggest it on github issues we might add that :-)